# Is this question possible?

Tags: questions

He is going to meet someone that (   ) has fired.

If I am curious about who this (   ) is, can I use this question: "Who is he going to meet someone that has fired?"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you intend to ask a question like this:

> Who has fired someone that he is going to meet?

Instead, you came close to asking this question:

> Who is he going to meet that someone has fired.

There are three people involved in the original sentence: the subject of "is going", the subject of "has fired", and the object of both "to meet" and "has fired".   You're curious about the subject of "has fired".   You need to start with that.

In your attempt, you started with the object of "to meet".   Your question tries to ask about the person who has been fired, not about the person who did the firing.

There are other nuances worth consideration, if you want your question to sound natural and fluent.   For example, the indefinite "someone" in the original statement likely deserves a more definite reference in the question.   Also, it's simpler to express the past-tense action of this semantic *agent*, rather than some present-tense resultant state.   Finally, unless the register is quite formal or some emphasis is needed for clarity, the verb of the subordinate clause can be contracted.   One way that I might phrase this question is:

> **Who fired the person that he's going to meet?**

In any case, the question that you phrased, "Who is he going to meet someone that has fired?" makes no sense.   From it alone and as a native speaker, I couldn't possibly guess what you were trying to ask.   It seems grammatically sound until the word "someone", at which point I am no longer able to parse it.

I'm glad to say that your question *about* this question is clear and sensible.   The first thing that you need to do is to put your curiosity first.   When you're curious about who did the firing, start with "who fired...?"

Comment: thank you, sir/ma'am, for typing so long a text just for me. my curiosity is now solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing *that* with *who* and adding a direct object:

*"He is going to meet someone who has fired a canon."*

**EDIT:**

Your quoted question has two part:

1. a grammatically correct question *"Who is he going to meet"*
2. an answer to the question *"someone that has fired."*

It is the answer that lacks a direct object.  The reader has no idea of what or who has been fired  - a person or a gun or a piece of pottery

Comment: sir, I wanted to know whether my question was grammatically correct. could you answer my question?

Comment: @KimHui-jeong  Please see my **EDIT**

Comment: If by "canon" you mean a piece of 18th century military hardware, the word is "cannon". "Canon" is a homonym, one of whose meanings is a particular rank in the Christian clergy.